# CentOS 7 - Cannot change subnet mask

Tags: centos7, subnet, mask

I just noticed that this CentOS 7 server's subnet mask is 255.255.255.0. It should be 255.255.255.240.

```
# ip a show ens32 | grep ens32
3: ens32: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 216.1.2.5/24 brd 216.1.2.255 scope global ens32
    inet 216.1.2.4/24 brd 216.1.2.255 scope global secondary ens32
    inet 216.1.2.6/24 brd 216.1.2.255 scope global secondary ens32
    inet 216.1.2.7/24 brd 216.1.2.255 scope global secondary ens32
    inet 216.1.2.8/24 brd 216.1.2.255 scope global secondary ens32
    inet 216.1.2.9/24 brd 216.1.2.255 scope global secondary ens32
```

I've tried unsuccessfully to change the subnet mask. The ifcfg-ens32 file has the correct prefix (/28). Even after restarting the network and rebooting the server the subnet mask is still 255.255.255.0.

```
# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens32
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
DEVICE=ens32
ONBOOT=yes
PREFIX=28
GATEWAY=216.1.2.3
IPADDR0=216.1.2.5
IPADDR1=216.1.2.4
IPADDR2=216.1.2.6
IPADDR3=216.1.2.7
IPADDR4=216.1.2.8
IPADDR5=216.1.2.9
DNS1=127.0.0.1
NM_CONTROLLED=no
```

The IP addresses are static and the NetworkManager is not installed.

How do I fix the subnet mask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the CIDR prefix for each IP address. Right now none of them have it specified.

```
PREFIX0=28
PREFIX1=28
PREFIX2=28
PREFIX3=28
PREFIX4=28
PREFIX5=28
```

Comment: It seems a bit difficult to find a good source for this. Can you come up with one?

Comment: @EsaJokinen It's undocumented except in the network-scripts themselves. But since these files are obsolete now (and were sort of deprecated back then) I wouldn't count on having an official source.

Comment: It's good it's obsolete. The syntax is quite horrible!